# Syntax for opening a new window and passing a parameter to it in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my C#/WPF app the user can click a button to create a new window to display some graphics.   Currently the code in the button handler looks like this  . . .

```
var window = (Window)System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("ShowGraphics.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
window.Owner = this;  // keeps the Window on top of the parent window
window.Title = "Show Graphics";
window.Left = 700;
window.Top = 500;
window.Show();
```

Now I want to pass a parameter to the constructor of my new window using constructor syntax, something like this (pseudocode . . . )

```
  Window myWindow = new Window("ParameterValue");
  myWindow.Show();
```

... but I don't know what the right syntax is for declaring the window with its associated XAML file and other properties and passing a parameter to be read in the constructor of the new window.

PS - and while we're on the subject, how do I return a value back to the main window where the button was?

***An Answer to the first part***
I think this is what Roman Ko was trying to get at when he wrote

```
"public partial class TestDialog : Window"
```

but instead of deriving it from the .Net Window class what I needed to do was derive it from my specific wizard-created class (Add > New Item... in VS2010).  Because Visual Studio creates both the .cs file, and the .xaml file at that time, the window is associated with its XAML layout through that means.   Then to pass the parameter, just do it via the constructor.  Thus invoking it . . .

```
    var window = new TheNameSpace.ShowGraphics("parameter"); 
    window.Owner = this;  // keeps the Window on top of the parent window
    window.Title = "Show Graphics";
    window.Left = 700;
    window.Top = 500;
    window.Show();
```

... and consuming it in the constructor . . .

```
public ShowGraphics(String sParam)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // do stuff
}
```

***An Answer to the PS***
One way is to override a method of the child window, e.g., *show()*

```
// Override Show()
public void Show (out string sResult)
{
    Show();  // call the base class method
    sResult = "foo";
    return;
}
```

... then, in the caller ...

```
string sReturnVal;
window.Show(out sReturnVal);
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you cannot do this when instantiating a window via the `App.xaml` `StartupUri` because it searches for a parameter-less constructor. If you remove the `StartupUri` and manually instance your window by overriding the `App.OnStartup` method and calling the constructor there it is possible.

Comment: I'm not wedded to StartupUri - I just want to know how to instantiate a window in C#/WPF, in such a way as to specify its XAML and pass a parameter to it.    Could you please show some sample code so I can understand your suggestion?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (if you don't want to follow the MVVM pattern):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        string inputParam = "some value";
        string outputValue;
        TestDialog dlg = new TestDialog(inputParam);
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            outputValue = dlg.OutputParam;
    }
}

public partial class TestDialog : Window
{
    public TestDialog() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TestDialog(string inputParam) {
        InitializeComponent();
        OutputParam = inputParam.ToUpper(); // for example
    }

    public string OutputParam { get; private set; }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do I associate the dialog to the XAML file defining it?                                                                    But I don't object to an MVVM pattern.   The goal is to allow the user to click a button and have a window appear with the graphics in it, where the graphics reflect parameters passed in when the window is created.  What would you suggest as sample code for doing this using an MVM or MVVM pattern?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, then you don't have to associate the dialog to the XAML in any special way. I think the second part of your question (about the sample code) is too broad.

Comment: What do you mean "you don't have to associate the dialog to the XAML in any special way"?   In your example you've defined a class called TestDialog which is an instance of Window.   Where does the XAML describing the layout of TestDialog get associated with TestDialog?   Instead of "Window" did you mean to use a _specific_ class, e.g., "MyWindow", where I've already defined "MyWindow" elsewhere using some wizard in Visual Studio so there's already a "MyWindow.cs" and "MyWindow.xaml" that are part of the project?

Comment: @user316117: TestDialog is what you create in Visual Studio. Select Add -> Window (Visual Studio 2013), and enter "TestDialog". That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should have been clearer, you cannot create an instance via `Application.LoadComponent`, `StartupUri`, or any other XAML based instantiation method available without a parameter-less constructor (it relies on there being one).  If you would like to provide a constructor with parameters you can create your window as you did in your second snippet:

```
var window = new ShowGraphics("parameter-value");
window.Show( );
```

Comment: But the second snippet was just **pseudocode**.  Any actual window will still need XAML to describe its layout, so what would the actual C# code look like to do that?

Comment: Well, your pseudo code was almost correct, except you want to create an instance of `ShowGraphics` not just a plain `Window`. `InitializeComponent` will handle the XAML portion of your control so be sure to call it in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of cases, you do not need to explicitly tell WPF where or what the XAML is for a `Window` control you create.  The code to do this is generated for you and executed by the `InitializeComponent` method defined in the generated code

Here is a cut and paste of the generated code created for the `MainWindow` in a WPF application.

**MainWindow.g.i.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// MainWindow
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/mainwindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        #line 1 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

        #line default
        #line hidden
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes")]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity")]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
    void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
        this._contentLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

I repeat, **you do not write/edit this code, it is generated for you automatically.**  All you need to do is call the constructor for your custom `Window` - `ShowGraphics` - and be sure the constructor you do call invokes the `InitializeComponent` method.

If you want to take a look at your own generated code, you can find it in the $(ProjectDirectory)/obj/$(Configuration)/ folder.